# Use service workers with Webpack dev-server inside Docker container

Tags: javascript, docker, webpack, service-worker, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to use service workers inside a web app using Webpack and Docker.

Everything I made for the moment is working well (service worker, webpack config, worker registration...)

Actually my app is running inside a Docker container, in this container I can start my webpack build to create all my JS files.

But now I would like to be able to use webpack dev-server and HMR with my service worker.

To do that I used https://github.com/oliviertassinari/serviceworker-webpack-plugin that correctly made a reference of my service worker inside the `manifest.json`

Then when I access through my web browser to my application, every built assets are found except my worker.

I run my dev-server using (I use [webpack-encore](https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore)), inside my docker container

```
encore dev-server --hot --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080
```

To load my assets the browser request them on `0.0.0.0:8080` but my worker is registered from `localhost:8000` so the request fail with 404 error because the worker is located `0.0.0.0:8080/sw.js` instead `localhost:8080/sw.js`.

I would know if this was possible to fix this behavior and made my service worker working inside the webpack-dev-server on a docker container.

I know service workers are listening only their scope, in my case `localhost:8000/*` but the webpack-dev-server is `0.0.0.0:8080`.

This is why I asking if this is possible to change this behavior to made it work, and if someone already had this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose port 8000 from your Docker container as well as port 8080. You must expose multiple ports from your Docker container for multiple web services on different ports.

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 8000:8000
```

[Official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose)

Comment: This will not work in my case because I have another container (the one that render my website) that already expose `8000` port

Comment: Did you try mapping to a different port using `docker run -p 8001:8000`?